# Export Datatable data to Excel in(XLSX) format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

The following code is working for now but I want this in XLSX format without any corruption message after opening the Excel.

```
protected void BTNExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtexp= ExportTrends(); //const

    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();             
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.xls");
        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        string[] images = TXTImages.Text.Split(new string[]{"<img"},StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (images.Length > 0)
        {   
            Response.Write(images[0].ToString());
            for (int i = 1; i < images.Length; i++)
            {   
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                string secondpart = images[i].Substring(images[i].IndexOf(',')+1);
                img.ImageUrl = LoadImage(images[i].Substring(images[i].IndexOf(',') + 1, secondpart.LastIndexOf('\'')));                        
                img.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output));
                Response.Write("<BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/>");
            }                    
        }
        Response.Write("<BR/>");
        ////// Create a dynamic control, populate and render it
        GridView excel = new GridView();
        excel.DataSource = dtexp;
        excel.DataBind();

        excel.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output));

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Empty);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you need to find a library capable of generating a real XLSX file. Have you tried Googling "C# XLSX library"?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but they use external libraries. i don't want to add external libraries to my project.

Comment: Well that's going to be tough for you. You see, XLSX is not really a simple format to just generate in your own code. That's why libraries exist. So you don't have to reinvent the wheel. What do you have against using external libraries?

Comment: yes,  so the final option is for me to use external libraries right?

Comment: What do you mean "final option"? It's the only reasonable option.

Comment: mean that I have to use external libraries. then only I can export the data to .XLSX format. I tried so many time with changing this code but not succeed

Comment: The code you provided doesn't generate a valid XLSX, or even a valid XLS file. That's all there is to it. And to generate a real XLSX file takes quite a bit of code. Which is why libraries exist to do it for you, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. All of which I've already pointed out to you.

Comment: Thank you mason. But the code written is working and export file into xls format.

Comment: No, you're mistaken. You aren't generating a real XLS file either. I know you might think it's working, but it's not. What you're creating is an HTML file and then serving it up with an XLS extension and MIME type. Which is pretty silly. Excel on Windows knows how to open it, though it might give you a warning message. But many other Excel clients will barf on this file. And for a while, Microsoft even broke this and tried to prevent it from working until enough people doing this terrible practice complained about it. Again, this is why it's good to use real libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you set a reference to Excel, and then something like the code sample below should get the job done for you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //connect with database
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=""Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"";Data Source=""demo.mdb"";User Id=;Password=";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select * from parts where Cost<1000 and ListPrice>500";
            DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            //export specific data to Excel
            Workbook book = new Workbook();
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
            book.Worksheets[0].InsertDataTable(this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable, true, 1, 1);
            book.SaveToFile("sample.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("sample.xlsx");
        }
```

Comment: Using Excel Interop in an ASP.NET application is really not a good idea, it is very prone to errors and also is not even supported by Microsoft. See the following link: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)